# Shuld be a delay in a FreeRTOS task main loop?

Tags: task, freertos

Is it necessary to add some delay into the infinite loop inside a FreeRTOS task (created by `xTaskCreatePinnedToCore()`)? Also, in my case, since the function `aws_iot_mqtt_yield` already takes a timeout (`100`) I tend to think the extra task delay is unnecessary.

My task looks like:

```
...
while(1) {
  error = aws_iot_mqtt_yield(&m_client, 100);

  check error...

  vTaskDelay(10 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You shouldn't need to add a delay. In fact in my opinion it is bad practice as it means you could be suspended at two different points in the task which can lead to very confusing program flow and is hard to debug.

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but your explanation to it is odd. What if task takes mutex (or any other resource) somewhere - The task may be suspended at two different points. So what??